# Chrome does not prompt to save login/signup credentials in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So I'm quite new to angularjs, and actually I just inherited this code.

So this the signup process:

1. User clicks sign up, sign up modal appears
2. User fills up sign up fields, clicks submit
3. Another modal appears, telling user that sign up is successful and confirmation email has been sent to email
4. User provides confirmation url, *then prompted an option to save login credentials of previous registration*

If a registered user is logged in, there are totally no prompts whatsoever in Chrome, but everything's fine in Firefox.

My questions is:

what triggers the prompt? I figured that it showed up somewhere, so I'm rather close to getting this right.